# Oneboxes appear to be broken in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

Across SE chat, oneboxes appear to be broken.

[image]

[image]

And feed items are being posted differently:

[image]

Can we please have our oneboxes back to normal?

Comment: Do they use the API?

Comment: That last onebox was from a feed bot connected to the feed URL `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds`.

Comment: (all screenshots link to the transcript)